# How to support multi-person(more then 2) calls in webrtc(android) by only one Peerconnection?

Tags: android, webrtc

I'm use webrtc in android, now I want to support multi-person calls, when I check the webrtc's org.webrtc.PeerConnection class , I found that the PeerConnection support multi receivers in getReceivers() function as follow:

```
public List<RtpReceiver> getReceivers() {
    Iterator var1 = this.receivers.iterator();

    while(var1.hasNext()) {
        RtpReceiver receiver = (RtpReceiver)var1.next();
        receiver.dispose();
    }

    this.receivers = this.nativeGetReceivers();
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(this.receivers);
}
```

It looks like the PeerConnection support more then one receivers.

I want to know is there any way to support multi-person(more then 2)calls use only one PeerConnection?

Answer (score 3):

No, RtpReceiver is a subsystem to receive RTP stream and not the WebRTC endpoints. PeerConnection does not support more than two endpoints. You need central servers to enable conferencing/multi-user calls.